# What to ignore in bower.json

Tags: javascript, json, open-source, bower

I have [a library](https://github.com/kentcdodds/genie) that I'm developing and I'm publishing it to bower. Right now I'm ignoring everything except `genie.js` (the library) and `genie.min.js`. Is there value in having the `README.md` or the travis build file or the demo files or anything else? It seems to me that the reason someone adds your component to their project is so they can use it in their product and they don't want their file system polluted, am I wrong?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You're right, just the minimum. I would go a step further and drop the minified file, which is the best practise in Bower, as users are most likely using a build system and having an additional minified file is just wasting space.

You can easily ignore everything but one file by using globbing in the `"ignore"` property in bower.json like this:

```
"ignore": ["./!(genie.js)"]
```

Comment: Hmmm... Hadn't thought about that... I think I'll do that. This will encourage good behavior: using a build system. Thanks!

Comment: As a follow-up question. Is their a way to ignore all but that one library file? Right now I just have an array that lists the files and directories I want to ignore. I would love to do it on a share rather than ignore basis...

Comment: Yes, you can use globbing. So ["*", "!genie.js"] should do it, but there's a bug: https://github.com/bower/bower/issues/296 I orginally wanted a `include` prop which would do the opposite, but people didn't agree...

Comment: I agree with you. I'll see if I can get the work around to work for me. Thanks. Perhaps for completeness sake, you could add that ignore array to your answer. Thanks! :-)

Comment: Is this working for someone? I'm trying it and "./!(file.js)" doesn't exclude anything